# Fast converging sums involving tetrations

Tags: number-theory, transcendental-numbers, tetration

Loosely speaken, Liouville's theorem shows that rational series converging "too fast",
have a transcendental limit. The concrete criterion is somewhat cumbersome and hard
to check.

Now my question :

Is

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{k \uparrow \uparrow n}}$$

a transcendental number for all natural numbers n>=2 ?

Is Liouvilles criterion helpful here ?

And finally, is the sum

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty {\frac{1}{k \uparrow \uparrow k}}$$

a transcendental number ?

Comment: Which theorem by Liousville are you referring to, when you say "loosely speaking if a rational series converges "too fast" then the limit is transcendental"? Because these series do indeed converge tremendously fast, but I cannot see how this is connected to any of Liousville's Theorems.